# Is it possible to use multiple functions in xdmp:spawn in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have functions to run one by one, while running it in query console, I am getting timeout error. Is it possible to it through `xdmp:spawn()`?

Comment: Are you asking about `xdmp:spawn()` or `xdmp:spawn-function()` ?

Comment: xdmp:spawn-function()

Comment: it would be easier to provide a concrete example if you were to show some code or better describe the sequence of functions that you are calling. For instance, is it the same function invoked for each document returned from a search, a static list of function calls, or what?

Comment: @Mads Hansen : It is sorted out and working fine